# Is it possible to set a scrollTop on a page before the page is shown, on mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have no code for this, as this is more of a concept question.

I have a jquery mobile page that has a section at the top of its content that I want to place above the viewport. What i've done is set a silentscroll that is equivalent to the height of this section, which makes the window scroll to just below the section i want hidden.

The problem I have right now is that between when the page is loaded and shown to when the silentscroll is thrown, there is a split second of being able to see the section to be hidden, which makes the page look buggy given that you can see the silentscroll jump by 100-sum pixels to hide the section. This is clearly because the silentscroll is execute after the page is shown.

Is there a way to set a scrollTop to jquery mobile for it to be executed before the page is shown, preferably around when the pagebeforeshow event is thrown? As far as I know, this event is thrown after all the jquery mobile widgets are initialized, so couldn't the scrollTop be set on the window at this time?

**What I'm trying to do is set the scrollTop value on the window before the page is shown, so that the user doesn't have to see the page jump.**

I haven't been able to correctly set it up myself, I'm wondering if it's event possible.

Here's a quick image of the setup i'm trying to recreate. The green square is the section I want 'hidden', above the window. The blue box represents the mobile window and the grey box represents the document.

[image]

EDIT: I've checked mobile browsers; safari has no jump/jitter when it corrects for the silentscroll. Chrome mobile on IOS does have the jump/jitter, I wonder if it's a question of browser performance, or the way it queues DOM/viewport changes...

Comment: No I don't think that is possible. You could hide your html , set the scrolltop and show your html again.

Comment: Vimeo has this effect on [video pages](http://vimeo.com/71370784) to show more videos by that creator. Might be worth it to investigate out how they do it.

Comment: Vimeo for desktop yes, but mobile doesn't have this feature.

Comment: @Prusprus I am on a nexus 7 Android 4.3 in Chrome and it is working fine for me. What does mobile mean to you?

Comment: I was checking CrIOS and safari mobile. I admit I wasn't clear on the phone used, but I haven't yet tried it on Android myself. It worked fine on Safari on my IOS, but not on chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/gnsj6/

**CSS**:

```
.top {
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}

.container { 
    height: 1000px; 
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#topedge").offset().top + 200
}, 0, function() {

    $(".top").css("margin-top","0px");

});
```

I can't notice any jump with this solution. Neither with quite huge data (http://jsfiddle.net/gnsj6/4/)

Comment: That would still make it jump

Comment: fixed, now it should not jumps

Comment: Yeah true, but this causes another problem. After you set the scrolltop. The whole page will animate `200px` downwards.

Comment: if you make the page scroll with some speed set the two animations will be at the same speed and you will not notice anything.

Comment: The OP does not want to scroll. OP wants to scroll the page to a certain offset (without animating).

Comment: My hesitation with this answer was that it wasn't using jquery mobile - specific methods, but it seems that scrolling using the animate resolves the jump issue. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: you're welcome, honestly I wonder how it can works.. but it works so it's fine!

Answer (score 0):

Add a class that hides the page, after you set scroll top remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like this.
Hide your `body` (with `visibility`, otherwise you can't scroll):

```
....
<body style="visibility:hidden;">....
```

And do this with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').scrollTop('200px').css('visibility','');

});
```